# FlutterError: List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: flutter

I'm currently working on app to fetch data through my API but when i satrt it it throwing the error
**FlutterError: List is not a subtype of type Map<String, dynamic> **.
Data through my rest API -

```
{
    "author": {
        "username": "jhinku",
        "first_name": "jhinku",
        "last_name": "mamoni"
    },
    "content": "",
    "parent": null,
    "likes": []
},
```

This is just an small part of json.

and in **main.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('https://myapiaddress'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
// If the server did return a 200 OK response,
// then parse the JSON.
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
// If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
// then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class Album {
  final String content;

  Album({
    required this.content,
  });

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      content: json['content'],
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<Album> futureAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
            future: futureAlbum,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data!.content);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }

          // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the error i'm currentle getting `FlutterError: List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type Map<String, dynamic>`

I get some infos about this error from the internet is that API returns JSON array not json object so that is List not Map, But i don't know how to implement it, As i'm a beginner in flutter.
how do i rectify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the fetchAlbum method to return all albums from the API:

```dart
Future<List<Album>> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('https://myapiaddress'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
// If the server did return a 200 OK response,
// then parse the JSON.
    jsonDecode(response.body).map((albumJson) => Album.fromJson(albumJson)).toList();
  } else {
// If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
// then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class Album {
  final String content;

  Album({
    required this.content,
  });

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      content: json['content'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's giving me two errors- 1- A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'List<Album>' doesn't allow null. 2- A value of type 'Future<List<Album>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<Album>' .

Answer (score 0):

Thank you the problem has been solved.